# Images not showing in Google Sheets on iOS

Tags: image, google-sheets

I’ve got spreadsheets that I’ve created and have images put into cells using the IMAGE function, and taken from the internet. They’re viewable on my Mac, and other people’s sheets they’ve shared with me have the images shown fine, but on my own iOS devices, the images never seem to appear for my own sheets.

I have set the privacy settings to viewable for anyone with the link, but that hasn’t worked. Any ideas?

Comment: This site is about programming questions, not questions about technology in general. A better place to ask this question would be in the [Google Sheets subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/sheets)

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I'm new here and thought it was okay as another similar one was accepted.